# Cannot use the property data() from DocumentSnapshot

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I cannot use the property `data()` on DocumentSnapshot. It gives me an error in the console. here is the exact error:

> auth.service.ts(72,20): error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Observable'.

I tried getting the data in multiple different ways. All of these techniques were errors.

Service:

```
constructor(
  private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
  private afs: AngularFirestore,
  private router: Router,
  public db: AngularFirestore
) {
    this.user = afAuth.authState;

    this.user.subscribe((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.userDetails = user;
        console.log(this.userDetails);
      } else {
        this.userDetails = null;
      }
    })
}

getUserName() {
  (this.isLoggedIn()){
    const userD = this.db.collection('users').doc(this.userDetails.uid);
    const doc = userD.get();
    return doc.data().firstName;
  } else {
    console.log('user not logged in');
    return "nothing";
  }
}
```

Comment: can you provide more details

Comment: What details would you like me to provide? @SudarshanaDayananda

Comment: can you provide the code of `userD.get();`

Comment: thats a function in firebase

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot fourth one down @SudarshanaDayananda

Comment: updated the constructor @SudarshanaDayananda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`userD.get()` returns you an observable of `DocumentSnapshot`, so you cannot call `data()` on that. So you need to subscribe. In this case it seems that you want to return the data to a component (?) so I suggest you return an observable:

```
import { take, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

// ...

getUserName() {
  if(this.isLoggedIn()){
    const userD = this.db.collection('users').doc(this.userDetails.uid);
    const doc = userD.get();
    return doc.pipe(
      // add take if you only want data one time, which closes subscription
      take(1),
      map(d => d.data().firstName)
    )
  } else {
    console.log('user not logged in');
    // need to return an observable
    return of("nothing");
  }
}
```

Then in your component you subscribe to `getUserName()`, either by manually calling `subscribe` or using the `async` pipe in template.

Comment: So I tried this like this I am not sure If im using subscribe properly

this.userObservable = this.authService.getUserName().subscribe(
        (userN)=>{
          this.apComp.username = userN;
        }
      )

Comment: I declare the userObservable as userObservable: Observable<any>
the this.apComp.username varible is a string.

Comment: the error I receive is this error TS2740: Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<any>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more. @AJT82

Comment: I figured it out I needed to have a subscription object instead of an observable object they need to update the docs on this whole thing, what you wrote makes a lot more sense then google

Comment: Great, glad you figured it out while I was sleeping ;) Glad I could help you on the way!

Answer (score 0):

According to this document,  you can't use `userD.get().data()`. try `userD.get()` or `userD.data()`

```
const userD = this.db.collection('users').doc(this.userDetails.uid);

var getOptions = {
  source: 'cache'
};

userD.get(getOptions).then(function (doc) {
    // check if firstname exist in doc
     console.log(doc)
 }).catch(function (error) {
 });
```

I follow from https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/get-data.

Comment: here is the error I get when using this code::::::::       


error TS2345: Argument of type '{ source: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'GetOptions'.
      Types of property 'source' are incompatible.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"server" | "default" | "cache"'.

Comment: Please try this https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.GetOptions about the type of GetOptions